# How do you properly push an existing file with git / github actions?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm using github actions right now to compile any commits to a python file (out.py) and then I want to push that file to another branch (output). This works perfectly, the problem is the second time I call that, because the file exists on the other repo it starts failing.

The error is completely unrelated, it says that I haven't pushed anything using git add, when I have. (I think it might have to do with me using fetch incorrectly and having the python file be overwritten, not sure.)
How do I force this to overwrite the other file, or am I going about this incorrectly? (I want the structure of the repo to only be that one file and I've generated it as an orphan branch)

This is my branch pushing setup.

```yaml
      - name: Push to output branch.
        run: |
          git fetch
          git checkout output
          git add out.py
          git commit -am "Automated Build ${{github.event.head_commit.message}}"
          git push -f origin HEAD
```

Comment: git commit -am is a shortcut to skip the previous `git add file`. 
Either use git add file and then got commit -m "message" OR directly git commit -am " message" ( in the latter case don't need to run git add command), does this work?

Comment: I was jumping around using -am and -m, didn't notice I still was using am here, I have the same problem still using -m once it exists in the branch.

Comment: can you check your your push and fetch URL (origin) using `git remote -v`? does that correlate with your repository in which you want to push?